# copy values from Object[,] Array to Object[][] Array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have two Arrays:

- an `object[,]` Array
- an `object[][]` Array.

I want to copy the values from the `object[,]` array to the `object[][]` array.

I have tried something like that

```cs
object[,] array1 = new object[arraySize, 4]; //Here are some values inside
object[][] array2 = new object[arraySize][];


for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    array2[i][0] = array1[i, 0];
    array2[i][1] = array1[i, 1];
    array2[i][2] = array1[i, 2];
    array2[i][3] = array1[i, 3];
    
}
```

But I got a `NullReferenceException`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You got the direction of your assignments wrong.

Comment: And why are you using `arrayCounter2` and not just `i`?

Comment: i have edited, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array2[i][0] = array1[i, 0];
```

Here you have a null reference exception because `array2[i]` is null. You need to initialize each element of `array2` before you can use.

> A jagged array is an array of arrays, and therefore its elements are reference types and are initialized to null.

[microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

```
// In your code, `arraySize` correspond to the numbers of rows in a multidimensional array. 
// In this example, rows = 2, columns = 4.
object[,] array1 = new object[2, 4] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 } };
object[][] array2 = new object[2][] { new object[4], new object[4] };

for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        array2[x][y] = array1[x, y];
    }
}

// print array2
for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array2[i]));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    array2[i] = new object[array1.GetLength(1)]; // array2[i] is null initially
    for(int j = 0; j < array1.GetLength(1); j++) {           
        array2[i][j] = array1[i, j];
    }
}
```

Try it out here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/f1XUXI

Comment: thaks, but got the same exception: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I added a fiddle so you can see it in action.